# JDK6 IA-64 vs x86_64 Multithreaded issues

Tags: java, multithreading, multicore, itanium

Has any programmer programmed Java-Multithreaded code and has seen different behavior between Itanium and x86_64 as code is running? Elements of unsynchronization or wrong locking on ConcurrentSkipListMaps or releasing of MappedByteBuffer ?
I face a very wierd issue where on IA-64 the java code does not run smoothly and correctly but yet on x86_64 I don't see errors.
I have read various posts in internet but most of them talk about C++. But yet Java uses native thread since 1.2. So I am wondering... anyone?

Comment: It would help to have the code. x86 are very permissive compared to other architectures (especially VLIW ones like IA64). As a matter of fact, programmers struggle with MT since the dawn of times, so to strictly answer your question: Yes.

Comment: Different JVM implementations *might* have different implementation "features" (bugs), JDK6 is ancient. Are you using native code?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch native no if you mean JNI. I use MultibyteBuffer,ConcurrentSkipListMaps,some runnables inside File.listFiles(accept()) pattern. and streams to write data.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Frankly it's too much of a code to read I am afraid. Thanks for your willingness but I can not give that burdain. In general however I use MultibyteBuffer,ConcurrentSkipListMaps,some runnables inside File.listFiles(accept()) pattern. and streams to write data at the exporter (consumer part )